# Is adding attributes to nodes in the web.sitmap a bad idea?

Tags: asp.net, sitemap, breadcrumbs, sitemappath

I using SiteMapPath with an xml file for data. I would like to use the same file for another menu, but I need to have more information attached to each node.

```
<siteMapNode target="_blank" url="~/Default.aspx" title="Home"  description="Home Page" >
VS
<siteMapNode url="~/Default.aspx" title="Home"  description="Home Page" >
```

So far it doesn't break on my box, but will I run into problems later? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doubtfull you'll run into any problems. Whatever is consuming your sitemap file is only going to parse known attributes. Extra attributes will go ignored.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft has always intended for siteMapNode elements to allow custom attributes on them. You can access the values of those attributes with the [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sitemapnode.item.aspx) on the SiteMapNode class.

The ASP.NET QuickStart Tutorials briefly mention this feature [here](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/navigation/sitenavapi.aspx#sitemap2).

Answer (score 1):

I use this approach quite often and for quite some time. It has not caused me any problems.  The only downside is the code needed to parse them.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answers. XML is meant to be eXtensible.